# Intellij IDE for Windows 7

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDE on Windows 7. Here **Shift + Up / Shift + Down** is not working for Line selection operation. How to get this, as it is default way in other editors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the key mapping in the settings (File -> Settings). Type in the search box (upper left) `keymap`. When on the keymap settings page find in the tree `Main menu -> Code`. There you find the `Move Line Up` and `Move Line Down`. Make a right click and select `add keyboard shortcut` to assign what you want. Most probably `SHIFT-UP` is already assigned to some action. It's up to you if you want to reassign it.